# Angular - Failed to Initiate module

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting the following error:

[Failed to instantiate module ContactsApp due to:
TypeError: undefined is not a function](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=ContactsApp&p1=TypeError:%20undefined%20is%20not%20a%20function%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fsrc%2Fapp.js:8:21%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.d%20%5Bas%20invoke%5D%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:35:36)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:33:394%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:7:290)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:33:207)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20gc%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:36:309)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:18:170)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fc%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:18:387)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Xc%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:17:415)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20HTMLDocument.%3Canonymous%3E%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:214:469)

When I comment out html5mode in app.js the error goes away, and when I navigate to /contacts the views/list.html template doesn't load. I'm fairly new to angular so I think I'm just overlooking something simple and I'm not quite sure how to trouble shoot it.

app.js:

```
angular.module('ContactsApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/contacts', {
                controller: 'ListController',
                templateUrl: 'views/list.html'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5mode(true);
    });
```

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="ContactsApp">
    <head>
        <title>Contacts</title>
        <base href="/" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Contacts</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12" ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="src/app.js"></script>
        <script src="src/controller.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's html5Mode (capital 'M').

```
angular.module('ContactsApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/contacts', {
                controller: 'ListController',
                templateUrl: 'views/list.html'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it's always the simple things the first time around.